# $X=S^2/{\sim}$ where any point on the equator is identified with its antipodal point. Compute $\pi_1(X)$ and $H_\ast(X)$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

My instructor gave me an idea. He used Van Kampen's Theorem to calculate the fundamental group, with $A=B=\mathbb{R}P^2$ and $A \cap B=S^1$ (the equator). I know $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is the quotient space of $S^2$ where each point is identified with its antipodal point. **How can $A$ and $B$ can be $\mathbb{R}P^2$ if we only identify points on the equator of $S^2$ with their antipodal points?**

By Van Kampen's Theorem, $\pi_1(X)$ is the pushout of $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2) \leftarrow \pi_1(S^1) \rightarrow \pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2)$ or $\pi_1(X)\cong \pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2) \ast \pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2)/N$. **How exactly do I find the normal subgroup $N$?** I know that $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}P^2)\cong \mathbb{Z}/2$ and $\pi_1(S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

I think I can use Mayer Vietoris sequence to calculate homology, with the same $A$ and $B$. If $n>1$, then $H_n(S^1)=0$ so $H_n(\mathbb{R}P^2) \oplus H_n(\mathbb{R}P^2) \cong H_n(X)$.

However, I'm stuck on calculating $H_0(X)$ and $H_1(X)$. I believe the Mayer Vietoris sequence looks like this
$\rightarrow H_2(X)\rightarrow H_1(S^1) \rightarrow H_1(\mathbb{R}P^2) \oplus H_1(\mathbb{R}P^2)\rightarrow H_1(X) \rightarrow H_0(S^1) \rightarrow H_0(\mathbb{R}P^2)\oplus H_0(\mathbb{R}P^2)\rightarrow H_0(X)$. This reduces to
$\rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\rightarrow H_1(X) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow H_0(X)$.

I know the sequence is exact so the kernel of the map going out of $H_1(X)$ is the image of the map coming in, but **how does that help or is there another way to calculate $H_1(X)$ and $H_0(X)$?** I don't know what the image or kernel of any of these maps is.

Comment: I think "a point" means "any point on the equator" in this context

Comment: @MaximeRamzi That seems plausible, otherwise the instructor's hint would not make sense. The OP should clarify this and edit the question.

Comment: Notice the typographical difference between $S^2/\sim$ and $S^2/{\sim},$ and notice how they're coded. The software is designed that way for a reason: A certain amount of space precedes and follows a binary operation symbol, but when {\sim} is in the code, there is nothing preceding or following the binary operation symbol, so that space is not there. I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can $A$ and $B$ be $\mathbb{RP}^2$ if we only identify points on the equator of $S^2$ with their antipodal points?

Let $S^2$ be the sphere as usual. Now, cut $S^2$ along its equator gives us 2 $D^2$ (disks). Since $\sim$ is generated by $x\sim -x$ for all $x$ **on the equator** (i.e. $x$ is equivalent to its antipodal point iff its on the equator). We finally obtain two identical quotient space $A\approx D^2/{\sim}$ and $B\approx D^2/{\sim}$ where the same equivalence relation in the restricted situation identifies $x$ with $-x$ if $x\in\partial D^2\approx S^1$. Now, you can easily prove that $A\approx B\approx \Bbb{RP}^2$.

Remark: I think you confused the definition of $\Bbb{RP}^2$ with $A,B$. Indeed, $\Bbb{RP}^2=S^2/(x\sim-x)$. But, after identifying the interior of the upper hemisphere with the interior of the lower hemisphere, you'll get $D^2/(x\sim-x)$ where $x\in\partial D^2$ which is just what your instructor mentioned in the first paragraph.

> How exactly do I find the normal subgroup $N$?

First, note that $X\not\approx\Bbb{RP}^2$ but $X$ is obtained by attaching $\partial(I^2/{\sim})$ where $(x,0)\sim (1-x,1)$ and $(0,y)\sim(1,1-y)$ to another identical copy of it (i.e. identifying the boundary of two $D^2/{\sim}$ together). Here is what it's like:

[image]

Let $U$ represent the blue half which is $\Bbb{RP}^2$ and $V$ be the other half. Clearly, $\pi_1(A\cap B)\cong \pi_1(S^1)=\langle a\rangle$. By Van-Kampen's Thm, $j_1:(U,x_0)\to(X,x_0)$ and $j_2:(V,x_0)\to(X,x_0)$ induce an epimorphism $j_*:\pi_1(U)*\pi_1(V)\to\pi_1(X)$. The amalgamated relation which is $N$ must be given by $i_{1*}:\pi_1(U\cap V)\to\pi_1(U)$ and $i_{2*}:\pi_1(U\cap V)\to\pi_1(V)$ so they have the form of $i_{1*}(a)^{-1}i_{2*}(a)=1$ where $a$ is a generator of $\pi_1(U\cap V)$. To see this, You can easily show that $N\subset \ker(j_*)$ using the commutativity of the diagram of this theorem, that is splitting $U\cap V\to X$ into two branches. Then, show the injectivity of $\pi_1(U)*\pi_1(V)/N\to\pi_1(X)$ which should be included in the proof of Seifert Van-Kampen's Thm.

We get $\pi_1(X)\cong(\pi_1(\Bbb{RP}^2)*\pi_1(\Bbb{RP}^2))/(aa=1,bb=1)$, but
since the generators of the two parts are the same (by the equivalence relation), we simplify the result to be $\pi_1(X)=\langle a,b\mid a=b,aa=1,bb=1\rangle=\langle a\mid aa=1\rangle\cong\Bbb{Z}/2$. Here $aa=a^2=1$ because in the picture $a^2\simeq$ (the outer boundary of the square and is a trivial loop).

> Compute $H_*(X)$:

I prefer Cellular homology in this case because $X$ is just $\Bbb{RP}^1$ with 2 $e^2$ attached by gluing their boundaries with $\Bbb{RP}^1$.

1. $H_0(X)\cong\Bbb{Z}$ because $X$ is connected. $H_p(X)=0$ if $p>2$.

For other cases, consider the cellular chain complex:
$$0\to\Bbb{Z}\oplus\Bbb{Z}\overset{\partial_2}{\to}\Bbb{Z}\overset{0}{\to}\Bbb{Z}\to0$$

2. For $H_2(X)$, Let's assign a counterclockwise orientation to 2-cells $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$, then we can see that $\partial_2(n\gamma_1+k\gamma_2)=0$ iff $n=k\implies Z_2(X)=\ker(\partial_2)=\Bbb{Z}$ because $\partial(\gamma_1)=2e^1$, $\partial(\gamma_2)=-2e^1$. So, $H_2(X)\cong\Bbb{Z}$
3. For $H_1(X)$, the image of the boundary map $D_1(X)\to D_0(X)$ is $0$ because the only 1-cell under the boundary map gives us $v_0-v_0=0$ which implies $Z_1(X)=\Bbb{Z}$ and from number 2, we know that $B_1(X)=im(\partial_2)=2\Bbb{Z}$ because $\partial_2(\gamma_1)$ wraps the equator two times and so does $\gamma_2$ (different directions). So, $H_1(X)=Z_1(X)/B_1(X)=\Bbb{Z}/2$.

To sum up,
$$
H_p(X;\Bbb{Z})=
\begin{cases}
\Bbb{Z} & p=0,2\\
\Bbb{Z}/2 & p=1\\
0 & \text{otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$

I think that Using MV sequence is a little bit complicated in this case, but you can check out [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557239/homology-of-quotient-of-3-sphere-by-identifying-antipodal-points-on-equator) which is a similar situation and that person uses MV sequence which I think it's more difficult than Cellular homology.

---

If this helps you solve the problem, please consider to click the tick to accept it because it took me some time to write it in Latex format...

Comment: A note: $D_i(X)$ represents the cellular chain group; $Z_i(X)$ is the group of $i$-cycles and $B_i(X)$ is the $i$-boundaries.

Comment: thanks for your answer! To calculate $N$, we look at the generators of $U \cap V$ and take their boundaries? So since the boundary of S^1 (square) $a$, how exactly do we get that $a^2=1$?

Comment: If you're doing this kind of math, then standard LaTeX and MathJax usage is worth knowing. See my edits to this answer and my comment under the question.

Comment: @Zebramuscles1234 First, $\pi_1(U\cap V)\cong\pi_1(S^1)=\Bbb{Z}$. As I pointed in the answer, $N$ is generated by $i_{1*}(a)^{-1}i_{2*}(a)$ (a should be included in the proof of the theorem) so we look at the intersection, since it has only one generator $a$, we see that $i_{1*}(a^2)$ in the blue part is homotopic to the outer boundary of the square (by path homotopy) so this gives us $aa=0$. Similarly, in the red part. The thing is, we need to put the generator into the two part and see what it's equal in order to get the amalgamated rel 'cause $\pi_1(U)*\pi_1(V)/N\to\pi_1(X)$ an isomorphism.