# How to image this space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $X$ be the space obtained by gluing the diametrical points on the equatorial circle of $S^2$, then how to image $X$.

I calculate the homology group of $X$ and get $H_2(X)=H_0(X)=\mathbb Z,H_1(X)=\mathbb Z_2,$. It implies that $X$ is orientable but is not a closed surface. Can we have a more intuitive description of $X$? For example, what is the boundary of X? How can we glue two $\mathbb P^2$ to get $X$?

Comment: It seems that you're talking about the space mentioned in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3733244/x-s2-sim-where-any-point-on-the-equator-is-identified-with-its-antipodal-p/3733674#3733674). Also please specify what do you mean by "an intuitive description"? Cell-decomposition or what?

Comment: Thanks. It seems that we can get $X$ by gluing two $\mathbb P^2$, how can we do it explicitly. And what is the boundary of $X$.